# Opening file from VS does work, but does not from compiled executable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cd

In my VS project I am defining the path to a file that I want to read relative to the location of the compiled executable of my application with `cd..//..//` and so on. This does work perfectly inside debug and release configurations in Visual Studio. However, if I directly run the generated executable, the file path does not point to the actual file. It seems like `cd` is something else, but I am not sure what it actually points to.

How should I define my path to a file relative from the generated executable?

Comment: No, the attached solution does not work for me. `GetModuleFileName` returns the `C` directory, which is not the location of the executable. I need to know the exe location.

Comment: Project > Properties > Debugging, note the value of the Working Directory setting.  That is not where the .exe file is stored.  Change it to $(OutDir) and it now behaves the same way it does when you run the program from the command prompt.